# Performance/cleanliness of if else statement in for loop

Tags: javascript

I am looping through an array and want to do something different on the last iteration. Currently, I have:

```
var arr= ["a","b","c"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i < (arr.length-1)) {
    alert("if");
  }
  else{
    alert("else");
  }
}
```

I have also considered:

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];

for (var i = 0; i < (arr.length-1); i++) {
    alert("if");
}
alert("else");
```

Which is better in terms of performance and/or clean code practice? Note that the alert calls would be more complex and use properties in the array(`arr[i]`). The array will never be too large(max ~10 entries)

Comment: In the first one you could also place `arr.length-1` into a variable so that it doesn't need calculated each loop iteration, since you're worried about performance (of course this is a micro-optimization and most likely won't ever have a noticeable effect).

Answer (score 1):

> The array will never be too large(max ~10 entries)

The array is very small, performance impact is negligible.

> Which is better in terms of performance and/or clean code practice?

The first one is "better" since the else is still part of the loop. It clearly shows your intent that your loop is still interested in the last item. The second one seems like it is ignoring the last item on the list, making the else portion totally separate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer the second solution over the first one, but with clear comments: "Perform the following over the first N-1 elements." and a matching comment for the last-element operation.

My rationale is that the looping is intended for the N-1 elements only and a check for "not last element" is included in the loop condition, thus the i < (arr.length-1) condition is redundant.

If you want to keep everything in the loop, I would switch it around:

```
if (i == (arr.length-1))
  // do something
else
  // do something else
```

This clearly shows that the exception is your last element. Again, state in your comments what you indend to do!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I try to prioritize readability over performance. Even if readability is subjective. Accordingly, the decision would largely be based on what your intent is for the loop, and what your intent is for the last element.

Concretely, if the last element processing is not a guard, or an exception I would probably expect to see something like:

```
for(var index = 0, length = arr.length; index < length; index++) {
   index < length - 1 ? something(arr[index]) : otherThing(arr[index]);
}
```

Inversely, if the last element processing is a guard or exception, I would hope to see it at the beginning of the for loop, with some explanation of why the last item needs to be protected from normal processing.

```
for(var index = 0, length = arr.length; index < length; index++) {

   // Comment explaining why this case is an exception.
   if(index === length - 1) {
     otherThing(arr[index]);
     return;
   }

   something(arr[index]);
}
```

Lastly, because this feels like a bit of an odd pattern, I would probably want to move the actual processing out of the loop. This helps to make it more apparent that we have a special case on the last item. Having the processing code for 'otherThing' and 'something' in the loop might make it more difficult to grasp the last item condition.

If performance proved to be unacceptably poor, I might consider other options but not until I had a solid set of metrics on the actual cause of the performance issue. A ternary (a ? b : c) or simple if/return in your loop is, subjectively, not going to be the performance problem.